# Explanation of trivial zeros of the Riemann Zeta Function

Tags: riemann-zeta

Why do negative even numbers plugged into the Zeta function produce a zero? The Riemann Hypothesis implies that the non-trivial zeros are connected to the primes, so how does that fit with negative even numbers?

Comment: That's an analytic continuation of $\zeta$, which is not very related to its series definition on $\left]1,+\infty\right[$ so dont be surprised if negative even numbers are zeros. If you want a proof, it uses the Gamma function 's analytic extension.

Comment: this answer is not so simple. Take a look [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Trivial_Zeroes_of_Riemann_Zeta_Function) for a proof.

Comment: For your second question, the effect of a zero $\rho$ of the zeta function  on the distribution of the primes is, roughly speaking, to put a term $\sim x^\rho$ into the explicit formula for the Chebyshev function (and thus an analogous term in the explicit formula for the prime counting function). The nontrivial zeros have $\Re(\rho)>0$  so they are important at large $x.$ Whereas the trivial zeros have $\Re(\rho)<0$ so they don't contribute anything at large $x.$

Answer (score 1):

The functional equation of the zeta function, needed to extend anatically that function to $\;\Bbb C\setminus\{1\}\;$ and one of the most astonishingly beautiful equations in mathematics, is

$$\zeta(s)=2^s\pi^{s-1}\,\sin\frac{\pi s}2\,\Gamma(1-s)\,\zeta(1-s)$$

Well, now for $\;s=-2n\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ , you get $\;\zeta(-2n)=0\;$ ...

Answer (score -3):

For example, the zeta function at $-2$ is $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ...$ which is trivially equal to 0.

Similarly, the zeta function at $-4$ is $1^4 + 2^4 + 3^4 + ... $ which is also trivially equal to zero.

It is trivial to see that the same holds for the function at $-6$, $-8$, ... etc. For that reason, these are considered the trivial zeros of the Zeta function.

Comment: Also, it is trivial to see that 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 +... (the sum of all positive integers) is equal to -1/12.